# How to configure nginx for a rails single page application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, single-page-application, unicorn, openresty

I am trying to configure nginx to render a Rails 4 single page application. The index page exists within a Rails template `index.html.erb`. Javascript and CSS are both on a CDN. The current configuration allows the page to load, and I can navigate the entire site. The issue comes when I try to reload the page or attempt to navigate to a page via the address bar: `mysite.com/about`. What am I missing? I have experience with single page apps but usually the page is external to Rails.

**I am using:**

- Rails 4
- Unicorn v4.3.1
- Openresty 1.5.11.1

**Nginx configuration:**

```
upstream rails_server {
  server unix:/var/www/mysite.org/api/shared/tmp/.unicorn.mysite-org.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server deferred; # for Linux
    server_name staging.mysite.org;
    client_max_body_size 5m;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      # proxy_cookie_domain api.local.mysite.org local.mysite.org;
      proxy_pass http://rails_server;
    }

    location ~* /application.*\.css$ {
      return 301 $scheme://css.mysite.org$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* /application.*\.js$ {
      return 301 $scheme://js.mysite.org$request_uri;
    }

}
```